# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS login screen freeze issue

Tags: login, 20.04, suspend

I am using the HP Pavilion laptop with the following config:

```
RAM: 16 GB
Processor: i7 8th gen
```

The issue is that when my laptop goes to sleep and when I wake it up, it's getting stuck on the login screen, and there's just no other way other than a hard shutdown to solve this issue. I tried waiting for it to come back to normal, but it doesn't. As a temporary fix, I had to disable the auto-sleep. Recently I closed the lid, but when I tried to log in after opening the lid, it was stuck on a black screen.

Comment: Are you definitely talking about sleep here or hibernation? If it’s hibernation have you got enough swap space allocated? It will need to be equal or more than the ram. What type of graphics do you have? Are the drivers up to date?